# SQL: Referencing calculated columns in other parts of the query

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2012

I would like to do the following in SQL Server 2012:

```
SELECT UnitPrice * Quantity as SubTotal,
       SubTotal * (1-0.13) as Tax,
       Tax + SubTotal as Total
FROM Invoice
```

As far as I know, this is not possible to do as written above, however I was wondering if there is a special way of identifying the column on the fly which could be referenced elsewhere in the query such as "Field list" (part of SELECT clause), as part of WHERE clause or in the ORDER BY clause.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Aliasing is the last part of query execution before `order by`. So you can reference the aliases only in  `order by` clause.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do the calculations in a `cross apply`.

```
select T1.SubTotal,
       T2.Tax,
       T2.Tax + T1.SubTotal as Total
from Invoice as I
  cross apply (select I.UnitPrice * I.Quantity) as T1(SubTotal)
  cross apply (select T1.SubTotal * (1 - 0.13)) as T2(Tax)
```

[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/4c550/1)

Answer (score 4):

Partial solution (which is enough in many cases, however) is ***with*** construction:

```
with Query as (
  select SubTotal as SubTotal,
         SubTotal * (1 - 0.13) as Tax,
         SubTotal * (1 - 0.15) as AnotherTax -- etc.
    from Invoice
)

select SubTotal,
       Tax,
       Tax + SubTotal as Total
  from Query
```

Comment: Nice suggestion, would it work with more than one calculated column? In the above example it is only Tax, but what if there were other calculated fields such as "Unit Price" and "Quantity" to calculate the "Subtotal" and then Tax calculation to be added to the mix. I can update my question if it helps.

Comment: @sam360: Yes, you can put as many claculated columns as you want.

Comment: Thanks, I updated my question. Your response seems to be workable, however there are more complicated examples in my requirement where the calculated columns can reference each other.

Comment: @sam360: That's why I've put it as "partial solution"; in case of complicated examples I'd rather create a VIEW with all calculated fields in it and use this view instead of the original Invoice table

Comment: Thanks, I really appreciate your help! 
I think CROSS APPLY takes care of it much better, even though it might not have the same performance as yours.
I would have voted for your answer in certain scenarios...